# jQuery on() fails to remove an element

Tags: jquery, dynamic

I'm doing a dynamic table to collect passengers personal data.
This table have above a control to add more rows at the end, every row is a copy of the first one, and that one have as last element a link that I use as a control for deleting that row.

The problem is that just the first row, the one that is not created dynamically, is the only one that is actually working and it's capable of removing itself.

So the page even stop creating new rows due to the lack of the initial row (but that's another issue xD).

This is the code I use to delete the row:

```
$('.remove').on("click",function(event){
    event.preventDefault;
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();

    //alert(str);
    newRowNum -= 1;
});
```

and here is the live site if you want need to chek it out:
http://www.micontrol.cl/~mvargas/wordpress/wp-transatacama/reservas-rapidas/tabladinamica.php

Comment: Marcos, please edit you question to also include enough of the HTML to allow us to see what the .remove element and its parent's parents look like.

Comment: Note that `event.preventDefault` doesn't do anything as the parentheses are missing (should be `event.preventDefault()`).

Comment: Your code will only works for element with class 'remove' initially present one the page. For applying it also on new elements you will have to put this selector in the descendant part : `$(selector).on('click', '.remove', function() {...});`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.on()` events are only bound to elements that are initially in the DOM with its default syntax.  [See the documentation for it](http://api.jquery.com/on/).  You need to have a second selector if you want to delegate the event to other elements.

Comment: I didn't get it but at the end of the "long" (not that long xD) documentation lies the answer, the last example, creates new elements and that elements as you said have the ability to create new ones too, :D.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <table id="test">
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td><a>Click</a></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>B</td>
            <td><a>Click</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <p>
        <a id="insert">Copy</a>
    </p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#test").find("a").click(function(){

          $(this).parents("tr").remove();

        }); 

        $("#insert").click(function(){

          $("#test tr").first().clone(true).appendTo("#test");

        });

      });

   </script>
```

Here is a fiddle for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/AdS8D/3/

**EDIT:** Added clone functionality to the fiddle.

Comment: thx, but it didn't worked out, it just do the same, dynamically created rows aren't affected at all. :(

Comment: @MarcosVargasMoran: I forgot to fix my fiddle link. Try now.

Answer (score 0):

Go back to using the clone technique, but use .clone(true) so that it copies event handlers as well.

Comment: so it would be clone instead if html()?? 
var addRow = $("#tabdata tbody").first().clone();
  then append the append(addRow)????

Comment: Yes, but don't forget to add true.  That means it copies styles, data and most importantly (in this case) event handlers.  When you copy the row with your existing code you're not attaching the event handler to the delete button.  With .clone(true) you don't need to :)

Comment: dude, i tried a lot using clone, it didn't worked, the answer i picked worked out, using clone() to create, or the simple html().
anyways thaks for you answer i'm leaving using html(), for now on ;D.

Comment: No worries mate - as long as you get it working, that's the main thing :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
$("#tabdata").on("click", ".remove", function(event){
    event.preventDefault;
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    newRowNum -= 1;
});
```